# 2GP packaging error: These entities are not supported: [NavigationLinkSet]

Tags: community, package, navigation, 2gp, digital-experience

I am creating a new package for communities.

I have included the communityTemplateDefination/lightning bolt/theme defintion and my NavigationMenu (in the navigation menu folder) but when I package it I am getting this error: These entities are not supported: [NavigationLinkSet]

I am using API version 52, and as per the documentation Navigation menu's are supported from API v46 onwards.

Looks like NavigationLinkset is considered as default for communityTemplateDefination but this was fixed according to [this](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YnpIQAS&title=unable-to-set-navigation-menu-for-theme-navigation-in-community-builder-when-updating-the-community-via-a-change-set).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to use a template or lightning bolt, can I suggest you consider packaging the (majority of the) actual community itself?

What I understood from Salesforce was that lightning bolts are effectively deprecated and not intended to move forward. You can find details on my experiences with packaging a community in [this earlier Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347145/how-do-i-package-an-upgradable-experience-builder-site).

In terms of the `NavigationLinkSet` issue, this metadata type does not appear in the [metadata coverage report](https://mdcoverage.secure.force.com/docs/metadata-coverage), which therefore tallies with the error you see. You cannot package this metadata. You can, however, package Navigation Menu instances - I did this successfully myself (though actually no longer use them in my package).