# Deploy Digital Experience from Scratch Org to a Sandbox

Tags: salesforcedx, b2b-commerce, digital-experience, network

We have created a digital experience in a Scratch Org and retrieved the source metadata. When we are trying to deploy the converted source medatadata to a Sandbox the following error is presented:

`Error  mdapioutput/networks/Samplenetwork.network  Samplenetwork  This URL is already taken.`

We have converted the source metadata using the `sfdx force:source:convert` command, and to deploy we have used the `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you enabled digital experience bundle and excluded the Site.com "blob" from the metadata you have pulled and that you are deploying?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347145/how-do-i-package-an-upgradable-experience-builder-site/347146#347146) for how to enable bundles etc.